# limiting the frequency of a broadcast receiver's invocations

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

i have a `BroadcastReceiver` that gets invoked by several system events
basically all it does is check something and then run a service if needed (everything here happens away from an activity, the receiver is registered at the manifest file)
once invoked i don't really need to do anything special for a period of time (say 15min), of course i could just return from `onReceive`, but that seems wasteful on battery if its invoked tens or hundreds of times,

i could sleep inside the `BroadcastReceiver` but that seems like a bad idea

is there an elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: if you are finished with the receiver however then its job is really done. It is invoked based on a trigger event so unless you want to set a counter of sorts it should be ok.

Comment: the receiver gets invoked every couple of seconds, doesn't that impact battery life (to just return and do nothing)?

Comment: Yes if it gets called that often lol, you could set a timer I guess like you said

Comment: I don't think immediately returning from a Receiver will cost that much, but if you really do want to do what you're describing, you could disable the Receiver using `PackageManager` upon the first run, set an alarm for 15 min. ahead, and implement another Receiver to get the alarm, and re-enable the first Receiver. Kinda convoluted, but if you really need that first Receiver to get all the broadcasts it does, that's about the most "elegant" solution I can think of.